# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a map in a project but I cannot because there is some error when I debug the application with the fragment.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

This is my .java file:

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
   }
```

And, This is my Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.inkadroid.mapa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name = ".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="My_KEY"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Also, I've added google_play_services library.

Visit http://i61.tinypic.com/2jdjaky.jpg

And, I get this error. If anyone know how to solve it, please tell me.

```
06-02 22:21:50.615: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.inkadroid.mapa/com.inkadroid.mapa.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException:     Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
06-02 22:21:50.615: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-02 22:21:50.615: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
```

Comment: Did you try dumping the `Fragment` inside a `ViewGroup`?

Comment: post your activity_main xml

Comment: your activity should extend fragmentactivity i guess or actionbaractivity

Comment: can you post the entire LogCat exception? towards the bottom of the exception log is usually an indicator of why the XML couldn't be inflated (ie: NPE etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to move `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml`.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and your **minsdk="8"** so you should change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and also change this

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag should be inside application tag. This one:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: it looks like the OP does have the meta-data within the application tag

Comment: but his googleplayservercies version is not inside application tag according to what he posted also he is setting min sdk version to 8 so he should extend fragmentactivity thats what I did in my project

Comment: ah whoops, I was looking at the wrong meta-data block

Comment: Also OP needs to replace the API key value with his key generated by the google API console.

Comment: @android_Muncher you dont usually post your api key publicaly because you have to post your package name and with the api key you can do a lot of bad works so thats fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your xml like:

```
 <fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and edit your main activity to extend FragmentActivity like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```